# Convert string date time to datetime in QGIS

Tags: qgis, datetime

I am trying to convert a string column that contains date and time values into a datetime column in QGIS. The format of the string column is (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss). I write the expression as to_datetime("DateTime", 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'), but get an error message saying that I cannot convert that specific column to datetime. As far as I know, the layer is saved as a GeoPackage.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the full DateTime field? At the moment the screenshot cuts it off halfway. JGH's solution below works for me.

Comment: Yes, I have added it to the original post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-2) says `mm` is for minutes, `MM` for months

Try with `to_datetime("DateTime", 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')`

[image]

Comment: It still gives me the same error /:

Comment: Make sure the `-` and the space are exactly the same characters in the input and in the expression (copy-paste them from one of the record)

Comment: There was an extra space in my original column, thank you so much!